# Subtract larger number from smaller number (Hex)

Tags: assembly, hex, subtraction

I'm was doing some practice problems for the system numbers. Everything was working good but I'm stuck in a problem where I subtract larger number from a smaller one in Hex system (base 16)

(1234 - ABEF) I started doing that;

```
4 - F = 5 (borrow 16 from 3 so it becomes 2)
2 - E = 4 (borrow 16 from 2 so it becomes 1)
1 - B = 6 (borrow 16 from 1 so it becomes 0)
0 - A = ?   I don't know what to do here ? where should I borrow from ?
```

I used an online calculator and it tells me the final answer is 
(1234 - ABEF = FFFF6645 )

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to borrow from, so the result becomes negative.

The assumption by the online calculator that you used is that you are working on 32-bit signed values, and since you are subtracting a greater number from a smaller, the subtraction of ABEF from 1234 wraps around and becomes FFFF6645, a.k.a. decimal -39355.

Side note: If you are on Windows, the built-in calculator can help you do these calculations in the "Programmer" view.

Answer (score 0):

Logic doesnt have a subtraction, subtract is done with addition.  Remember, twos complement, "invert and add 1".  When you do decimal math and you add 99+3  the first column is 9+3 = 2 carry the 1.  that number carried over goes into a carry slot on top, second column 1 (carry) plus 9 (first operand) plus 0 (placholder for second operand).  is 0 carry the 1 the third column is 1+0+0 = 1 carry the zero, and we can call it done.  you can visualize three rows, carry, first operand, second operand..  The carry slot is available on the first column.  Now think binary, you can do the exact same math in binary with columns (hex is just binary, in groups of four bits, if you were to do this with pencil and paper you would break the hex into individual bits).  so we know from school that a + b = a + (-b) right and we know that in binary -b is the twos complement is invert and add one.  so what if you were to simply invert and use that as the second operand, and the add one is a 1 in the carry slot in the first column, so 0x1234 - 0xABEF is the same as 0x1234 + (-0xABEF) = 0x1234 + (~0xABEF) + 1 = 0x01234 + (~0x0ABEF) + 1 (added some padding) = 0x01234 + 0xF5410 + 1 = 0xF6645.  or if you want to trim it to 16 bits then it is 0x6645.  if you are doing 32 bit then it is 0xFFFF6645, 64 bit 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF6645.  Just like in decimal 99+3 = 100 or 0100 or 00000000100 depending on how many places we want to fill with numbers.

What if we did 0x1234 - 0x0005 = 0x01234 + 0xFFFFA + 1 = 0x01224.  The padding to the left is zeros.  There was no borrow.  The other number there was a borrow and the carry out on the left is ones forever.  Or another way to think of it is the answer is negative.  a negative one in binary is invert and add one right so 0x001 inverted is 0xFFFFF...FFFFE for as many bits as you have in your alu or register, and then add one and get 0xFFFF....FFFF.  If it is an 8 bit register 0xFF, 16 bit 0xFFFF, 32 0xFFFFFFFF.  Same with the above 0xFFFF...FF6645.  Invert that and add one  0x99BA+1 = 0x99BB = 39355  or actually -39355.

0x1234 = 4660, 0xABEF = 44015, on the calculator 4460 - 44015 = -39355.